# Redirection of stdout to a file not working

Tags: python, linux, bash, io-redirection

I have a script that uses subprocesses to fetch HTML:

```
misha@misha-K42Jr:~/git/domain_classifier$ python webkit_retrieve.py error-cut.txt html/error -N 5
http://kurabo.co.jp HostNotFoundError
http://monarch.com HostNotFoundError
http://nssmgmt.com HostNotFoundError
http://sbcglobal.net HostNotFoundError
http://dynamixcorp.com SslHandshakeFailedError
http://groupe-synox.com RemoteHostClosedError
QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)
http://www.cnn.com NoError
http://pacbell.net TimeoutError
```

If I run the same script, but redirect output to a file, I get nothing in the output:

```
misha@misha-K42Jr:~/git/domain_classifier$ python webkit_retrieve.py error-cut.txt html/error -N 5 > stdout.txt
QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)
misha@misha-K42Jr:~/git/domain_classifier$ cat stdout.txt
misha@misha-K42Jr:~/git/domain_classifier$
```

Why is the output empty?  Should it not contain the same things that were printed to stdout in the first case?

**The question is not about merge stdout and stderr but why redirected stdout produce an empty file**

Comment: what do you get in the file?

Comment: The file is empty, hence `cat stdout.txt` prints absolutely nothing.

Comment: What is the python source for setting up the output file handles and doing the output itself?

Comment: If the output for both commands is **different** and `stdout.txt` is really empty then the python script acts differently if the stdout is redirected

Answer (score 36):

use `&>` for redirection, this should redirect `stdout` and `stderr` to designated file

Comment: I've been using `>` successfully forever and after 20 years it stopped (not sure if it has anything to do with the fact it's a python script that wasn't working). Now with the `&>` it worked. What's that all about?

Comment: As well: > didn't work for me for  a python script, but &> did

Answer (score 1):

You have sent stdout to the file, but your program is reporting errors which go to stderr.  To setup redirection of stderr, use `2>` syntax.

This link might help:  http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Comment: If it was echoing to `stderr`, wouldn't it still show at the terminal when the command is run with just `stdout` redirected?

Comment: good point.  It almost looks like stderr is actually being redirected, given the 'Pixel size' line's appearance

Comment: stderr is correctly being printed to standard output (the pixel size stuff) as per the default behavior on linux systems.  I don't want to redirect stderr, I want to redirect stdout.

Answer (score 0):

I think I was looking for solution a couple of moment ago.

Your best bet is to run something like this:

yourcommand | cat > redirectfile

Comment: ...what is `cat` doing here? Wouldn't `yourcommand > redirectfile` do exactly the same thing?

Answer (score -2):

Your output is going to stderror.  Try redirecting both stderror and stdout using the following:

```
<command> 2>&1 <file>
```

Comment: If the output was going to stderror, then I would see it in the console (as I do in the first case).  In the second case, the output is being redirected to a file, but the file ends up empty.

Comment: Doesn't work, file is not created